# Modify indexes of the elements of array

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to change idexes elements of my array. 
I have this array :

```
buttons: [
        {
          id: 0,
          url: SOMETHING, 
          buttonColor: COLOR,
          paragTitle: TITLE,
          paragPreview: DESCRIPTION,
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          url: SOMETHING, 
          buttonColor: COLOR,
          paragTitle: TITLE,
          paragPreview: DESCRIPTION,
        }
    //and other elements like these.
```

If my clicked button is 2 (for example) I wish that my buttons array was sorted in this way:

```
buttons: [
        { //object that previously had id 2 (but now is 0.)
          id: 0, 
          url: SOMETHING, 
          buttonColor: COLOR,
          paragTitle: TITLE,
          paragPreview: DESCRIPTION,
        },
        { //object that previously had id 3 (but now is 1.)
          id: 1,
          url: SOMETHING, 
          buttonColor: COLOR,
          paragTitle: TITLE,
          paragPreview: DESCRIPTION,
        }
       // the object that previously had id 4 , now is 2.
       // the object that previously had id 0 , now is 3.
       // the object that previously had id 1 , now is 4.
```

I'm trying to use filter:

```
let newArray = buttons.filter(
      (_, i) => i !== this.props.currentId
);
//after that I want to sort my array in the right method but I think that all my thinking is wrong.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this. First, you remove all elements before some index with `splice`, than you push those removed elements to the end of the array. Second argument of the `splice` function determines the index of the element that should become first.

```js
const buttons = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const removed = buttons.splice(0, 2);

buttons.push(...removed);

console.log(buttons);
```